# How can I sum a column of $90 then $20 without removing the dollar sign in access query criteria

Tags: ms-access-2007

It gives me error that data type mismatch in criteria expression , but can sum it without removing the dollar sign

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ sign is for *display* only. The values are truly numerics.

So, sum, add, or filter as for other numbers, and then apply the format, *Currency*, where you wish to display the totals.